# Difference between a paintmap and wetmap

Tags: dynamic-paint

Can somebody explain to me what is the difference between a paintmap and a wetmap? I'm currently studying dynamic painting and wondering the difference between these two outputs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a brush with a *Color* and a *Wetness* moves through a canvas, it lays paint.

As a result, the canvas gets

- a **color**, represented by the (RGBA) ***Paintmap***, and affected, for instance, by the *Dissolve* effect

  [image]

  (no dissolve in this example)
- some **wetness**, represented by the (greyscale) ***Wetmap***, and affected, for instance, by the *Dry* effect.

  [image]

Once the paint dries out (if it does), its color remains while its wetness goes away.

**Example shader** where the color is the paintmap, the specularity is the wetmap, the roughness is one minus the wetmap (there is also some alpha-based bump here):

[image]

Comment: That is cooool. Imagine how that can be in watercolour painting inside Blender.